# @JsonFormat converts Date with incorrect timezone

Tags: java, json, datetime, jackson

I have a simple POJO with a **Date** field with initial value coming in:

```
1985-09-17T01:00:00.000+0400
```

then this Date value gets mapped to a DTO with the **Date** field annotated:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX")
private Date dateOfBirth;
```

Then the result is shown:

```
1985-09-16T21:00:00Z
```

I have tried setting the **timestamp** property in `@JsonFormat`, but that didn't help and the date is still invalid.

How can I correctly convert the date?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value within a `java.util.Date` is the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch, which occurred at midnight January 1st 1970, UTC. As it's a number of milliseconds since a fixed epoch, the value within `java.util.Date` is the same around the world at any particular instant, regardless of local time zone.

So in your case it's better to use `ZonedDateTime` class if you use java 8 [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html)

Comment: When using Jackson `OffsetDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime` should work with [jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8). Since you have an offset (+0400), not a time zone (like Europe/Tallinn or Europe/Warsaw), `OffsetDateTime` is the right class to use.

Comment: OffsetDateTime + custom Json serialize + deserialize classes did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Both dates represents the same instant:

- 1985-09-17T01:00:00.000+0400
- 1985-09-16T21:00:00Z

When you print dates in java it uses the current timezone of the VM, but internally the `Date` class stores that information in a `long` representing the time in milliseconds since the epoch.

If you like you can get the a String representation of the date using a custom timezone using the [`setTimeZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone)) method of `DateFormat`:

> Sets the time zone for the calendar of this DateFormat object.

Here a simple snippet of code:

```
Date date = ...
DateFormat formatter = ...
TimeZone timeZone = ...

// Set a custom timezone
formatter.setTimeZone(timeZone);

// Get a string representation of the daet with a custom timezone
String formattedDateWithCustomTimezone = formatter.format(date);
```

Comment: Thanks! Is this `daylighttimesaving-proof`?

Comment: “Proof” is a big word. If you pick a time zone that has summer time (DST), it should honour it.